# batch file to search and replace a string

Tags: windows, string, search, batch-file

I need a batch file that should search the PC for all files issued today named as "example.ini" and replaces a string which will be in the second line of "example.ini", it should replace

`SERVER_IP=111.111.111.111` with another server ip `SERVER_IP=222.222.222.222`

How is that possible?

Comment: Is `SERVER_IP=` on any other line?

Comment: SERVER_IP= is on the second line only

Comment: Thanks.  Searching an entire drive and checking each `example.ini` for `todays date` could be very slow.  Is there a way to narrow down the search?  Will the `example.ini` have any other distinguishing features?  Maybe the IP address?

Comment: SERVER_IP=212.83.63.108
this is the main ip in "example.ini"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this on some sample files.

It will change the `example.ini` files on `c:\` and in subdirectories which contain `SERVER_IP=212.83.63.108` and will change it to `SERVER_IP=222.22.22.222`

It uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

```
@echo off
for /r c:\ %%a in (example.ini) do (
find "SERVER_IP=212.83.63.108" <"%%a" >nul && (
    echo processing "%%a"
    type "%%a"|repl "SERVER_IP=212\.83\.63\.108" "SERVER_IP=222.22.22.222" >"%%a.tmp"
    move /y "%%a.tmp" "%%a" >nul
    )
)
```

Comment: The Batch File Can Find The "example.ini" but when trying to replace i get error
'repl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch though i have repl.bat in same folder

Comment: I'd say that you are elevating the batch file with admin permissions.  Place `repl.bat` in the `c:\windows` folder so it is on the path.

Comment: Thanks A  Lot It Works Now It Was Able to replace the string in my "example.ini" thanks for all your effort

Comment: @admdrew The code for repl.bat is already hosted on Stack Overflow and also DosTips.com and including it every time it is used would create huge posts - so I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Change String1 by String2 in the second line of files named example.ini that has been created today in any subdirectory of drive c:

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Arguments:
    rem     %1 = search string
    rem     %2 = replace string
    rem     [ %3 = file in where to replace ] 
    rem            this parameters is internally used by the 
    rem            batch file while processing

    rem chech for parameters
    if "%~2"=="" goto :EOF

    rem retrieve parameters
    set "_search=%~1"
    set "_replace=%~2"

    rem check if asked to replace in a file 
    rem this will be done recursively from this same batch
    if not "%~3"=="" (
        set "_file=%~3"
        goto doFileReplace
    )

    forfiles /P C:\ /S /M example.ini /D +0 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE findstr /c:\"%_search%\" \"@path\" >nul && %~dpnx0 \"%_search%\" \"%_replace%\" @path "

    goto :EOF

:doFileReplace
    echo "%_file%"
    set "_tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.tmp"
    break > "%_tempFile%"
    (for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%l in ('findstr /n /r "." "%_file%"') do (
        if %%l EQU  2 (
            set "_text=%%m"
            echo !_text:%_search%=%_replace%!
        ) else (
            echo %%m
        )
    ))>>"%_tempFile%"

    copy /Y "%_tempFile%" "%_file%" >nul 
    goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit windows Edlin (a dos editor) is available.

```
12 
New text
e
```

is an edlin script that writes "New text" on line 12 of a file. Type

```
edlin
```

then

```
?
```

To use

```
edlin c:\folder\filename.ext < edlin.script
```

You must use short filenames. File must be under 64K lines.