# Find text and replace it with CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make an CMD program that can find text in a text file and then replace it with something else.
Example:
I want to find: maleEquip1
and I want to change it to: anInt165
Is that possible with a CMD program?

Comment: CMD program is called a Batch script.

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23087463/3603806 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764521/batch-file-to-search-and-replace-a-string

Comment: Ok, Ty for pointing that out.
and thanks for the links it helped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Comment: Go to This Page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087463/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-within-a-minute-for-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But it's very uggly. I would suggest to not reinvent the wheel. If it's possible to use 3rd party software take a look at a tool called fnr (http://findandreplace.codeplex.com/). You can call it from your cmd with the desired parameters. It's realy fast and easy to use.